# Force the value incremented by "step" input number

Tags: javascript, html

I created an input of type number. Minimum value 1, maximum value 100. Step 5. However, I can enter values other than step for this input. Eg 7 instead of 5-10-15.

I would like the manually entered values to be automatically increased to the step value.
The user enters 7 - after leaving the input it is 10. I am trying onfocusout but I have no idea how to do it.

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="5" onfocusout="this.value = Math.round(step);">
```

Example. The user enters 13 - gets 15. He enters 27 - gets 30.

Answer (score 2):

you can :

- get the result of value divided by 5
- round the result to near integer
- and multiply it by 5 to get the nearest 5 value of the input entered by user

  ```
  this.value = Math.round(this.value / 5) * 5;
  ```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="5" onfocusout="var result = Math.round(this.value / 5) * 5; this.value = (result) ? result : this.min ;">
```

Comment: Great solution! But is it still possible to keep the minimum value? Now I can call 0 :)

Comment: yes i edit my reply

Comment: you can use `var result = Math.round(this.value / 5) * 5; this.value = (result) ? result : this.min ;` if result of calculation is 0 you can get input mi with `this.min`

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of listening for `focusout` events you should listen for [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) events, which are triggered whenever the user does anything that implies they are done entering a value. This will make the behavior more consistent across browsers and devices.

Second, you can round a value to the nearest multiple of X by doing `Math.round(value / X) * X`, and you can restrict a value within [A, B] using `Math.min(Math.max(A, value), B)`.

Finally, the `min`, `max` and `step` HTML attributes directly correspond to properties on the JavaScript [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) object, which is the object bound to `this` inside the event listener.

Combinging all of this together, you get this.

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="5" onchange="this.value = Math.min(Math.max(this.min, Math.round(this.value / this.step) * this.step), this.max)">
```

Note that in your code the `min` attribute is `1` which isn't a multiple of `5`, and that tells the browser to accept values in the sequence [1, 6, 11, 16, ...] which breaks our code. If you want multiples of 5, you'll need to make sure the min attribute is a multiple of 5 as well.

All of that JS code inside an HTML attribute is hard to read, so you might want to use a proper event listener at this point, which lets you divide the problem into smaller functions.

```js
function clamp(a, value, b) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(a, value), b);
}

function roundTo(multiple, value) {
    return Math.round(value / multiple) * multiple;
}

function roundToStepOnChange(event) {
    const roundedValue = roundTo(this.step, this.value);
    const clampedValue = clamp(this.min, roundedValue, this.max);
    this.value = clampedValue;
}

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("change", roundToStepOnChange);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="number" min="5" max="100" step="5">
```

I set the min attribute to 5 in that example so you can see it running without any issues.